# Spring doesn't map comma delimited request parameter to list when parameter value is double encoded

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, urlencode

I have a request parameter: "test". The value is a comma separated list.

Spring binds the values to a list correctly if parameter is:

```
test=aaa,bbb
```

or:

```
test=aaa%2Cbbbb
```

but if it is double encoded like:

```
aaa%252Cbbbb
```

Spring could not bind it properly to a List. The list has only one value: `aaa%252Cbbbb`.

Can you please help how to solve this issue?